# Enable deep sleep in HP laptop on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: grub2, suspend, 22.04

Is there a way to enable deep sleep on my HP laptop with Ubuntu 22.04?

Changing `/etc/default/grub` to

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash mem_sleep_default=deep"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet splash mem_sleep_default=deep"

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

and executing `sudo update-grub` after restart `/sys/power/mem_sleep` will remain

```
s2idle
```

The kernel is updated (`5.15.0-27-generic`) but looks like that S3 is not supported

```
sudo dmesg | grep -i acpi | grep supports
[    0.192166] ACPI: PM: (supports S0 S4 S5)
[    0.216466] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: OS supports [ExtendedConfig ASPM ClockPM Segments MSI HPX-Type3]
```

Comment: Exactly my same problem ... i cannot write the /sys/power/mem_sleep file,  even with sudo -i ... i think is not the right thing to do write a /sys virtual path ... so 'im looking for solution too (XPS 15 9510 - Ubuntu 22.04)

Comment: I am facing also the same problem on fedora 37